# Inside a minipage centering or flushing environments disables \color command (Is it a bug?)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, pdftex, color, minipage, bugs

The next is the MWE that demonstrates the failure of pdflatex and LaTeX to color text that is inside minipage in a center or flushleft/flushright environment using command `\color`. XeLaTeX works fine and this makes me to think that it probably is a bug. `textcolor` command works without this problem but this is normal because creates it's own"environment". A tabular environment made me think that an empty environment inside center or flashleft could solve the problem... but doesn't.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newenvironment{emptyenv}{}{}


% Usage: Run with pdflatex and with LaTeX... no color... 
% Run with XeLaTeX... color is ok...
% Test the commented colors in other places with all engines...
% Replace center environment with commented flashleft...
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
%\color{green} % works on all
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
%\color{red} % Doesn't work with pdflatex or LaTex... but works with XeLaTeX
\begin{center}
%\begin{flushleft}
%%\begin{tabular}{c}
\LARGE\bfseries
%%%\begin{emptyenv}
\color{blue} % Doesn't work with pdflatex or LaTex... but works with XeLaTeX... inside tabular works on all
Test (Colored?) 
%%%\end{emptyenv}
%%\end{tabular}
%\end{flushleft}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I just asking if it is a bug that we have to report or if I am losing something important like: "This is why we have the `\textcolor` command!". If the second, please tell me where to find info.

**Edit: My version is : pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)**

Logfile here (runned pdflatex and gave black text): https://sites.google.com/site/koleygrfreelancer/home/readywork/testtitlecolor.log?attredirects=0&d=1

Comment: works fine for me with pdflatex.

Comment: Works for me too with pdflatex, TL 2017 on Linux with daily updates -- by the way, there's a second `\begin{document}`

Comment: Also works for me using latex+dvi2pdf

Comment: My version is pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

Comment: off-topic: instead of `\begin{center}...` I suggest `\centering` to avoid additional vertical spaces.

Comment: @koleygr Can you update to texlive2017?

Comment: I use my distro's provided software if no reason to change... But I have other OSs to check there with older and newer texlive

Comment: @koleygr: I don't remember that there has been an issue with `\color` inside nested environments in TL 2016, but this does not mean there was none

Comment: The document produces the error `! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.` please edit to be error free and show the log you get from the document

Comment: @koleygr: The Linux distro packages are often quite strange. Rather install TL directly from TL mirrors

Comment: @DavidCarlisle sorry... I have edited...I think it is a second begin{document} I had.

Comment: show the log I would guess you have non matching .def files somewhere (the text os coloured blue in pdflatex)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, you want me to ren pdflatex and show the log?

Comment: yes run pdflatex, if the output isn't blue show the log file

Comment: I just checked the text is blue in texlive 2016 pdftex as well as texlive 2017

Comment: .log file added @DavidCarlisle

Comment: that's weird log looks more or less as expected minor version differences here and there

Comment: I think I have to report to ask at unix.SE to find people with the specific OS... It is probably a debian problem... I will try on ubuntu too. (Which tag do you recomend to remove to use linux instead?)

Comment: What happens if you add some text after begin{center}?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, sorry for so late answer... I had some problems with my pc these days and came back much later. I tried your suggestion and with a text after `\begin{center}` the output is colored with all the compilation ways (latex, pdflatex, xeletex)...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't affect latex in general, but Debian packaging of texlive. (Not sure if really have to flag it... but I think this is the right behavior)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is still there on my Debian pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian)

The comments made me realize that it is a bug in Debian packaging and I am going to open a bug and report it right now.

Here added the link:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894364.

After that I will flag the question as off-topic since it affects just Debian distribution and not texlive in general.

PS: Please let me know someone more experienced if the texlive-latex-recommended  (that contains the `xcolor` or texlive-latex-base is the most possible source of the problem)